# Value of $\cos\theta$ when $\theta$ is very small

Tags: trigonometry

What happens (actually why) to the value of $\cos\theta$ when $\theta$ is small enough that its higher powers that is $\theta^2$ (and more) can be neglected?

Comment: It's close to 1.

Answer (score 7):

Taylor series:
$$
\cos \theta = 1 -\frac{1}{2}\theta^2+\frac{1}{24}\theta^4+\dots
$$
as $\theta \to 0$.